# Can I read just the key from plist?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, plist, key-value

Can I read just the key from plist without its value, also if I know the value can I read the key ?

Comment: What if different keys have the same value? What must happen then?

Comment: @WTP: No Keys have the same value and the case will not happen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Reading .plist:**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];    
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

**Getting all keys and all values:**

```
NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allKeys];
NSArray* allmyValues= [myDictionary  allValues];
```

**Getting all keys for an values object:**

```
NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allKeysForObject:myValueObject];
```

Comment: `myDictionary` should really be an `NSDictionary` here, not an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use [`allKeysForObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/getObjects%3aandKeys%3a) method which returns,

> A new array containing the keys corresponding to all occurrences of anObject in the dictionary. If no object matching anObject is found, returns an empty array.

From that array you can get the *key* by invoking the `objectAtIndex:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-[NSDictionary allKeysForObject:]`*.

---

### Example

```
NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeysForObject:@"My Value"];
if ([keys count] != 0) { // to prevent out-of-bounds crashes
  NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
  return key;
} else {
  return nil;
}
```

---

<sup><sub>*Dunno why it returns an NSArray object instead of an NSSet object, because keys are not ordered. Oh well.</sub></sup>

Comment: I have added an example. I didn't know about that method :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to read the values at app's installed folder:

```
 NSString *PListName=@"ExamplePlist";
 NSString *_PlistNameWithExtension=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",PlistName];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:_PlistNameWithExtension]; //3

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"%@",[myDictionary description]); 
NSArray *AllKeys=[myDictionary allKeys];
```

Jhaliya's method has not worked for me, then I tried this method.